# Can I adjust the way GUI applications are grouped?

Tags: gui, ubuntu-dock

I'm using the default Ubuntu dock but I'm frustrated by one of its behaviours, the way that if you open application A via application B, the dock treats A as an instance of B. For instance, say I click a link in my Slack, it will open firefox as a slack window, and the firefox instance won't have my password manager extension. If I then open a zoom link, it will open the zoom app as an instance of slack. Now say I have to open a new firefox window for some work related reason. I click the firefox icon in the dock, but now I have two firefoxes, one of which has a zoom icon and one of which has a Firefox icon. Its driving me mad to be honest - working from home is stressful enough as is. Can I make Linux open applications as simple instances of themselves, so that firefox is always considered firefox, zoom always considered zoom etc?

I tried moseying about in the Dock options, but I think the issue is deeper than that, since it also applies to alt-tab. If you can give me any help, it really would be much appreciated.